Stripe Firebase mobile payments: Android @Jetpackcompose
I am doing a donation app for my final year project in college in kotlin, with pure Jetpack compose based in ComponentActivity(). I am trying to install the stripe api. I need to have a server side, but instead of making one I am trying to use my Firestore. stripe has a repository with a program to install the necessary dependencies in the project, using FB CLI, noje.jc and npm, but when come to deploy them i am getting errors. i can see the functions on FB console already, but they are all red, with errors. I think i cant deploy them properly because of dependencies conflicts, with the versions. The videos im following and the repository are from 2022.
I dont know how to solve this conflicts or clean my project and maybe start fresh, but even if i clean it, i would follow the same steps. I am stuck. I dont need much, just a way to set up payment from donors to charities. In that case can be only 1 donor and 1 charity. It is only for presentation purpose, as this project is a prototype.
These are the links i am following:
https://github.com/stripe-archive/firebase-mobile-payments
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nw7rOijQKo8https://github.com/stripe-archive/firebase-mobile-payments
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNM8vb96yF4&t=237s
https://docs.stripe.com/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=android&ui=payment-sheet
Alternatively, I was in touch with Stripe and they told me that they have a solution called Connect, that accept payments from customers, and payout to sellers and service providers and I could use it to accept donations and send them to charity organizations.
https://docs.stripe.com/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide
I dont know what to do.
I tried npm audit fix, Remove-Item -Path .\node_modules -Recurse -Force, npm install firebase-admin@latest firebase-functions@latest - then realized that they need specif versions, npm outdated, npm update. and it keeps saying there is a error the loader.

Detailed stack trace: TypeError: async_hooks_1.AsyncLocalStorage is not a constructorat Object. (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/trace.js:6:24)at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)at Object. (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/logger/index.js:26:17)at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)

